# Exclude specific sub-directories using apache commons fileutils

Tags: java, apache-commons

I want to list all the files under current directory but excluding all the files within the subdirectory and it's subdirectories using apache commons lib.

For Example : *If my current directory is --  A   and its subdirectory as B, C ,D

B having subdirectory as b1,b2 (b1 has b12 as its subdirectory)   and C having c1 , c2... 
now I want to list all the files in C,c1,c2, D (excluding B , b1 ,b12 , b2 )*

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Have a look at the `FileUtils.listFiles()` method with the `dirFilter` parameter: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use org.apache.commons.io.FileFilter, there's a [good example](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/package-summary.html) of how to use it in the JavaDoc.

For example I have a directory structure like:

```
/tmp/testFilter/A
/tmp/testFilter/B
/tmp/testFilter/C/c1
/tmp/testFilter/C/c2
/tmp/testFilter/D/d1
```

Then I could list only the files under C and D with the following code:

```
public class FileLister {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        File dir = new File("/tmp/testFilter");
        String[] files = dir.list(
            new NotFileFilter(
                new OrFileFilter(
                        new PrefixFileFilter("A"),
                        new PrefixFileFilter("B")
                )
            )
        );
        listFiles(dir, files);
    }

    private static void listFiles(File rootDir, String[] files) {
        for (String fileName: files) {
            File fileOrDir = new File(rootDir, fileName);
            if (fileOrDir.isDirectory()) {
                listFiles(fileOrDir, fileOrDir.list());
            } else {
                System.out.println(fileOrDir);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IOFileFilter fileFilter1 =   FileFilterUtils.notFileFilter(FileFilterUtils.nameFileFilter("A", null));
IOFileFilter fileFilter2 =   FileFilterUtils.notFileFilter(FileFilterUtils.nameFileFilter("B", null));
FileFilter fileFilter =   FileFilterUtils.and(fileFilter1, fileFilter2 );
List<File> files =  (List<File>)FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs(dir ,TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE ,(IOFileFilter)fileFilter );
 for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++) {
  System.out.println(files.get(i));
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. I had to use `FileFilter` and not `IOFileFilter`. Thanks