# FileUtils.listFiles to exclude specific file extensions from listing

Tags: java, apache-commons, fileutils

I use this code to get all the files from a given directory recursively.

```
List<File> fileList = (List<File>) FileUtils.listFiles(new File(directoryName), null , true);
```

I would like to exclude some files from listing, so second parameter value of method isn't suitable for this purpose.
I tried to use also notFileFilter, but I can't use it recursively.

```
FileFilter fileFilter1 =   FileFilterUtils.notFileFilter(FileFilterUtils.nameFileFilter(".info", null));
List<File> fileList = (List<File>) FileUtils.listFiles(new File(directoryName), fileFilter1, true);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exclude specific sub-directories using apache commons fileutils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20658841/exclude-specific-sub-directories-using-apache-commons-fileutils). For sure, you should adapt it.

Comment: @GiancarloRomeo : I edited question.

Comment: You can find a nice solution here too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056221/recursively-list-files-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **other overload** of the [`listFiles`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#listFiles(java.io.File,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter)) method:

```
FileFilter notInfoFilter = FileFilterUtils.notFileFilter(
        FileFilterUtils.suffixFileFilter(".info", IOCase.SYSTEM));

Collection<File> files = FileUtils.listFiles(
        new File(directoryName), notInfoFilter, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE);
```

Answer (score 1):

For Java 8 and above you can do it with easily stream api

```java
List<File> filteredList = fileList.stream().filter(f -> f.getName().endsWith(".some_extension")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't list all the possible file extensions, just what is needed to be excluded.

Comment: @plaidshirt Then use `f -> ! f.getName().endsWith(".info")`